# Surfacing information from an AngularJS component

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

The documentation says

> Outputs are realized with & bindings, which function as callbacks to component events

The handler is defined in the controller of the feature that contains my component.

```
$scope.handleStatusChange = function (sc) {
  console.log(sc);
}
```

It is bound in markup to the component.

```
<search-context
  centre-code="4321"
  on-status-change="handleStatusChange">
</search-context>
```

When I invoke the handler in the code of my component the handler is called but the parameter is undefined. I have unsuccessfully tried expressing the parameter in various ways.

```
ctrl.onStatusChange(ctrl.status);
ctrl.onStatusChange({ value: ctrl.status });
```

How do I pass the parameter?

Is there a required signature for the handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample from the docs implies there's a matching convention between attribute names and parameter names.

```
function HeroDetailController() {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.delete = function() {
    ctrl.onDelete({hero: ctrl.hero});
  };

  ctrl.update = function(prop, value) {
    ctrl.onUpdate({hero: ctrl.hero, prop: prop, value: value});
  };
}
```

```
<hero-detail ng-repeat="hero in $ctrl.list" hero="hero" 
  on-delete="$ctrl.deleteHero(hero)" 
  on-update="$ctrl.updateHero(hero, prop, value)"></hero-detail>
```

Rewrite so that the name in the markup binding matches the attribute name in the object passed when invoking the callback.

The handler implementation need not match, just the component code and markup.